# How to pass Object object in functional interface/lambda call

Tags: java, generics, lambda, functional-interface

So, I have a piece of code that goes like

```
public static void printStuff(Object[] stuffs, Function<?, String> func) {
    for(Object stuff : stuffs) {
        String stringStuff = func.apply(stuff);
        System.out.println(stringStuff);
        // or whatever, what is done with that String is not relevant
    }
    // ...
```

This method is to be called with arrays of different types, and corresponding `func` value, for example:

```
printStuff(arrayOfClasses, (Class<?> c) -> c.getSimpleName());
printStuff(arrayOfStrings, (String s) -> '"' + s + '"');
printStuff(arrayOfObjects, o -> o.toString());
```

so I definitely need my *stuffs* to be `Object[]`, because it is the first common superclass of the different types amongst the method's calls.

And on compilation, I get:

```
MyClass.java:6: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to CAP#1
        String stringStuff = func.apply(stuff);
                                        ^
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

My guess is that *javac* rants for the parameter I give to the `Function<?, String>` call, whose type, `Object`, does not `extend` `Object`.

So my question is, *how can I pass an `Object` parameter to a `Function<?, String>`?*

I can change the interface types to `<Object, String>`, but it breaks my others calls (with `Class[]`, `String[]`, etc) and it would imply losing pretty much the whole point of genericity, wouldn't it?

Unless there is some way to change my `stuffs` type to something like `<? extends Object>[]`, or a generic type, and I'm pretty sure it's not possible.

Thanks in advance, folks.

EDIT:

if I change my method to a generic one, *i.e.*:

```
public static <U> void printStuff(Object[] stuffs, Function<U, String> func) {
```

I still get a compilation error :

```
MyClass.java:6: error: method apply in interface Function<T,R> cannot be applied to given types;
            String stringStuff = func.apply(stuff);
                                     ^
  required: U
  found: Object
  reason: argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to U
```

Comment: can't you `public static <T> void printStuff(T[] stuffs, Function<T, String> func) {`??

Comment: and the [explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).

Comment: nope, alas. See my edit

Comment: You didn't change your signature as RC proposed.

Comment: @Maaaatt oops, read too fast. works indeed -- as long as I don't forget to change the type of the inner `for` loop. Daaang, I was pretty sure type variables arrays were not possible though

Comment: @RC make your comment an answer, so that I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to use:

```
public static <T> void printStuff(T[] stuffs, Function<T, String> func) {
    for(T stuff : stuffs) {
        // ....
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As for the first code:

```
public static void printStuff(Object[] stuffs, Function<?, String> func) {
    for(Object stuff : stuffs) {
        String stringStuff = func.apply(stuff);
        System.out.println(stringStuff);
        // or whatever, what is done with that String is not relevant
    }
}
```

You are getting this error

```
MyClass.java:6: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to CAP#1
```

You get that error because the `?` could be any more specific class, e.g. you could also pass an argument func of type `Function<String, String>`.

You could fix that by declaring the signature like

```
public static void printStuff(Object[] stuffs, Function<Object, String> func)
```

or in a generic way:

```
public static <U> void printStuff(U[] stuffs, Function<? super U, String> func) {
    for(U stuff : stuffs) {
        String stringStuff = func.apply(stuff);
        System.out.println(stringStuff);
        // or whatever, what is done with that String is not relevant
    }
}
```

It is essential that the type of the array is equal to (or a subclass of) the first type parameter of the `Function`.